# Implementing All-in-one-events Calendar in Android Studio

Tags: android, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I  want to integrate All-In-One-Calendar Wordpress widget with my android app.

**Update**

I followed the example [here](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/wordpress-to-android-app-tutorial/) but I am getting [404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoDM6.png).

I need to sync calander in my app with the website.